# Integral over infinity of $F(x) = e^{ix}$

Tags: integration

how to calculate integral of following function over infinity ?

$F(x) = e^{ix}$  ($i$ imaginary)

$$
\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ix} \, dx
$$

Comment: $\lim_{a \to \infty}\int_{-a}^{a}e^{ix}dx = \frac{e^{ia}-e^{-ia}}{i}$ use [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula), and note it converges to $\delta(0)$ as $a \to \infty$ (see [Relationship to dirac delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function#Relationship_to_the_Dirac_delta_distribution)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integral does not exist in the usual sense obviously, so this depends on what meaning you put in it. Say, you want to understand $h(t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{i xt} dx$ as a (Schwartz) distribution. Then for any test function $f$,
$$
\left\langle h,f\right\rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{i xt} dx\, f(t)dt =\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{i xt} f(t)dt\, dx  \\
=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \hat f(x) dx = {\tau} f(0),
$$
by the Fourier inversion formula. This means that $h(t) = \tau\, \delta(t)$, in the sense of distributions. Therefore, "substituting $t=1$" (which is quite meaningless though) "gives" $\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{ix}dx = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

This is up to some factor the [Fourier transform of the unit function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Distributions) $f(x) = 1$, thus the Dirac delta distribution $\delta(\xi)$.

And this evaluated for non-zero argument, thus resulting to $0$.

WA seems to be a bit more rigorous: 
It states $0$ only as Cauchy principal value ([WA answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_%7B-%5Cinfty%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20e%5E%7Bix%7D%20dx))

Comment: Please any body could give me detailed reference , i know about duality of Fourier transform for Dirac function , just I'm searching  how they proved it

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_0^{\infty}e^{ix}dx=\left[\frac{e^{ix}}{i}\right|_0^{\infty}=\left[-ie^{ix}\right|_0^{\infty}=\left[ie^{ix}\right|^0_{\infty}=i-e^{i\infty}$$
this result not converge, are you sure the sign in the exponential is correct?

Comment: consider it is Fourier transform for x(t) = 1

Comment: sorry, you right